# Athena: Convert column to different values

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I would like to convert a column to another value, kind of like having a map.  I am currently doing something like

```sql
SELECT col1,
    col2,
    CASE
        data = 'data1' THEN 'd1'
        WHEN data = 'data2' THEN 'd2' ELSE data
    END AS converted_data
FROM some_table
```

Which works fine, but I really have a bunch of other possibilities, maybe 20 or more.  It can potentially even get to hundreds in the future.

Is it possible to have the map as a table, and convert the values from that table? I believe you can use `JOIN` but that seems it might be pretty expensive?  Is there a way to use `CASE` without writing each statement and just basing the values from that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is not a way to use a case statement without writing each condition to do what you are trying to accomplish.

If your end goal is a mapping to change the value of a column to something else and that could change or is a large number of items; for easy maintenance you would want to use another table which then is going to require a join or the use of a sub-query.

Here are 2 working examples with test data to show how those work:

Left Join:

```
#CTEs with test data
with convert_data as (
    select *
    From (
            values('data1', 'd1'),
                ('data2', 'd2')
        ) as convertdata (ddatavalue, datareplace)
),
some_table as(
    select *
    From (
            values('1', '1', 'data1'),
                ('2', '2', 'data2'),
                ('3', '3', 'data3')
        ) as sametable (col1, col2, ddata)
)
#query showing how to do the join
select col1,
    col2,
    coalesce(datareplace, ddata) as converted_data
from some_table st
    left join convert_data cd on cd.ddatavalue = st.ddata
```

Sub-query:

```
#CTEs with test data
with convert_data as (
    select *
    From (
            values('data1', 'd1'),
                ('data2', 'd2')
        ) as convertdata (ddatavalue, datareplace)
),
some_table as(
    select *
    From (
            values('1', '1', 'data1'),
                ('2', '2', 'data2'),
                ('3', '3', 'data3')
        ) as sametable (col1, col2, ddata)
)
#query showing how to do the sub-query
select col1,
    col2,
    coalesce(
        (
            select cd.datareplace
            from convert_data cd
            where cd.ddatavalue = st.ddata
        ),
        ddata
    ) as converted_data
from some_table st
```

Which one will perform better over the other will really be dependent on your data, structure and data file format.  Test both and see which one works better for you.